# Connect to VPN working inside WSL from Windows environment

Tags: linux, windows, networking, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a remote VPN set up, to which I can only connect to via Linux machines. As of now, I do have access from WSL to this VPN, meaning I can ping and interact with the hardware that is only visible inside the VPN.

Now I need to be able to send and receive data from these devices, or in other words, I need to be able to ping them from Windows. Can I expose this VPN from my WSL-Subsystem to Windows? Or somehow route my traffic through WSL?

I am connected via `vpnc` on Linux, and `wsl hostname -I` does show me the IP-Address WSL seems to have on the VPN.

The reason for this is that I have some proprietary software which is capable of communicating with proprietary hardware over TCP/IP. The detailed manner with which this communication is established / what kind of data is exactly sent is largely unknown to me.

As I am not the only person interested in such a connection, WSL is appreciated for ease of use and ease of setup for non-technical folks.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: WSL is not a full VM so it may be you cannot do what you are trying to do.

Comment: That’s a clear _maybe, but_. Probably would work, but why bother. Instead, please describe your use case in greater detail. How would you send and receive traffic from these devices? Is it simply a TCP connection? What kinds of clients are we talking about, some proprietary software?

Comment: You might get further by using a Linux VM.